# What is wrong with the double dash (--) in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

When I use the double dash comment in `Sql Assitant`, it works fine

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabTest 
-- WHERE  . . .
```

But when I submit the same query programmatically, say with Java. It is not recognized as a commented line. Why ? The [documentation](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2414_020A/2414ch03.05.08.html) does not say anything about it, does it ?

Therefore I always use `/*   */` and it works every time. but still I'd like to know why the double dash does not work when submitting queries programmatically ?

Comment: "It is not recognized as a commented line." - what does it mean? Ignored or an error is generated? How does your query look like in Java?

Comment: Think about it this way. The `--` is a line comment.  But you're not feeding **lines** to the method, you're feeding it a single string.  There is no way for the method to know when the commented line ends. So you end up commenting out everything after the `--`.   Hopefully that makes sense.